# How do I create clusters from a dataset in SAS? My attempt at the solution is below;

Tags: sas

I am looking to create clusters based on the code below. “w”, “x”, “y” and “z” are the column headings in my dataset.  I keep getting the errors such as variable “w” not found, variable “x” not found, “variable “y” not found etc… even though I know I have spelt the column headings right in the code. Does anyone know why I keep getting these errors?

```
proc means data=sdp_policy_data;
var Policy_Status Competitor_Policy;
run; 

proc fastclus data=sdp_policy_data maxc=8 maxiter=10 out=clus;
var w x y z;
run;
```

Comment: Column headings, depending on your viewer, may be the variable labels, which in turn can be different than the variable names, which are required by the `var` statement.  Do a `proc contents data=work.spd_policy_data` and add the results to your question.  The output will be a listing of the data set's column (i.e. variable) names and labels.

Comment: @Richard Hi Richard, thanks! I cannot upload the results to this question as the data I am working with is confidential. "w", "x", "y" and "z" are just dummy labels I used for this question. Never the less when I run the code you suggested I get a table with the dataset's column headings and their attributes. Is this table supposed to help?

Comment: Post a proc contents from your output, that should not be confidential. And if you can't get something to work with your data, try it with the examples from the documentation. If it works, then it's likely your data not the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this example code

```
data have;
  attrib
    w_hat    length=4 format=date9. label='W'
    x_result length=8 format=6.4 label='X'
    y label='Y'
    _z label='Z'
  ;
  w_hat='01-jan-2010'd;
  x_result=1.2345;
  y=7;
  _z=21;
run;

ods html close;
ods listing;
options nocenter;
proc contents nodetails data=work.have varnum;
run;

ods html;
```

The output for the variables should look like

```
          Variables in Creation Order

#    Variable    Type    Len    Format    Label

1    w_hat       Num       4    DATE9.    W
2    x_result    Num       8    6.4       X
3    y           Num       8              Y
4    _z          Num       8              Z
```

The `Label`s, being W, X, Y & Z, *may* appear as column headers in what ever viewer you are using.  The procedure will require `var w_hat x_result y _z;`